# Changing lines to inset axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib v. 3.0.3. I wanted to use inset axes to zoom in on a location in an imshow plot and then plot the zoomed in sections outside the main image. I was playing around with the inset axes using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import (inset_axes, InsetPosition, mark_inset)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
Z2 = np.random.rand(512, 512)

ax.imshow(Z2, interpolation='gaussian', cmap = 'RdBu', origin='lower')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', bottom=False, top=False, right=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False, labeltop=False, labelright=False)

# inset axes...
axins_1 = ax.inset_axes([0, -1, 1, 1]) # bottom left, outside main plot
axins_1.imshow(Z2, interpolation="gaussian", cmap = 'RdBu', origin='lower')
axins_1.tick_params(axis='both', bottom=False, top=False, right=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False, labeltop=False, labelright=False)
# sub region of the original image
axins_1.set_xlim(100, 150)
axins_1.set_ylim(85, 135)

ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins_1, edgecolor='0')
#mark_inset(ax, axins_1, loc1=2, loc2=3, fc="none", lw=1, ec='k')

# inset axes...
axins_2 = ax.inset_axes([1, -1, 1, 1]) # bottom right, outside main plot
axins_2.imshow(Z2, interpolation="gaussian", cmap = 'RdBu', origin='lower')
axins_2.tick_params(axis='both', bottom=False, top=False, right=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False, labeltop=False, labelright=False)
# sub region of the original image
axins_2.set_xlim(400, 450)
axins_2.set_ylim(200, 250)

ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins_2, edgecolor='0')
#mark_inset(ax, axins_2, loc1=2, loc2=3, fc="none", lw=1, ec='k')

# inset axes...
axins_3 = ax.inset_axes([1, 0, 1, 1]) # top right, outside main plot
axins_3.imshow(Z2, interpolation="gaussian", cmap = 'RdBu', origin='lower')
axins_3.tick_params(axis='both', bottom=False, top=False, right=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False, labeltop=False, labelright=False)
# sub region of the original image
axins_3.set_xlim(400, 450)
axins_3.set_ylim(400, 450)

ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins_3, edgecolor='0')
#mark_inset(ax, axins_3, loc1=2, loc2=3, fc="none", lw=1, ec='k')

plt.show()
```

Here, the main plot is the top left while the top right and both bottom pictures are the zoomed quantities. This generates almost exactly the plot I am after *inside the Jupyter notebook*. However, I have two issues that I'm looking to fix.

My first issue is that when I save the plot it comes out as follows

[image]

which clearly cuts off the zoomed images. I was wondering how to fix this?

The second issue is that the lines running from the subsections of the main plot to the zoomed images cross over in multiple places. What I would like is to keep the boxes around the subsections but change the lines. However, from [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.indicate_inset.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.indicate_inset) it seems you can't remove the lines only, as changing edgecolor does the colouring for both the box and lines.

What I would like is to have an arrow leading from the section pointing to the correct zoomed image or some other way of labelling the sections and their corresponding zoomed images. However, I haven't been able to find a way to do this. Is this possible? And if so, how do we do it?

The alternative way to do this would be to make subplots and simply plot the zoomed regions in the subplots. However, in this approach I am at a loss as to how to identify each subsection with the corresponding zoomed plot.

Comment: did you try using `tight_layout` or `constrained_layout` when saving to get everything displayed on your image?

Comment: Also, if you need to draw lines between two axes (e.g. if you just use subplots rather than inset axes), you could use a [`ConnectionPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch). See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/connect_simple01.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connect-simple01-py) for an example.

Comment: This is two questions.  The second question - there are four lines, two of them with visibility True and two with visibility False.  Toggle as you see fit

Comment: Sorry I should have noted that the box and the lines are returned from the add_inset command.

Comment: @JodyKlymak what is the add_inset command? I just searched for it and nothing came up. Do you mean indicate_inset_zoom? And this is my issue; _I don't know how to toggle_. Toggle where? In which property? What is the argument I am supposed to be toggling?

Comment: @tmdavison yes, tight_layout plots all the plots in the saved file but they are all fixed in the top left corner of the plot only while the rest of the plot is whitespace. Moreover, the lines coming from the subsections of the main plot extend all the way through the zoomed images and into the whitespace. And thanks for suggesting ConnectionPatch, I had never heard of it but it looks like what I had in mind. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: to answer your question above: `indicate_inset_zoom` returns a rectangle patch and a tuple of 4 `ConnectionPatch`s. Two of these are visible, two are not. For each of the patches in that tuple, you can use the `.set_visible(True)` method to change the visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always roll your own simplified `inset` function.

Here I'm using `subplots` to control my layout to help ensure I don't draw outside of the bounds of my `Figure` (which is why your `Figure` clips your `Axes` when saving to file).

Additionally, I set up my own rectangle and `ConnectionPatch` so that I'm only drawing a single `ConnectionPatch` per desired inset with the arguments I need. This enables me to have explicit control over where the arrow starts and ends.

In the function I provided

- `arrow_start` is an xy coordinate in proportional units on the Rectangle
  (e.g. (0, 0) is the lower left hand corner of the rectanble, (0, .5) is the center left, (0, 1) is the upper left, (1, 1) is the upper right, etc.
- `arrow_end` is an xy coordinate in proportional units on the inset Axes (e.g. (0, 0) is the lower left hand corner of the inset Axes, so on so forth.

You can use these two parameters to explicitly place your arrows where you think they go best on your figure to not overlap with other `Axes`

I also moved some of your style setting code to the top as default settings to be used.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, ConnectionPatch
import numpy as np

plt.rc('xtick', bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False)
plt.rc('ytick', left=False, right=False, labelleft=False)
plt.rc('figure', facecolor='white')

def indicate_inset(axin, axout, arrow_start=(0, 0), arrow_end=(0, 0)):
    (x0, x1), (y0, y1) = axin.get_xlim(), axin.get_ylim()
    width = x1 - x0
    height = y1 - y0
    
    rect = Rectangle(
        [x0, y0], width=width, height=height, 
        transform=axout.transData, fc='none', ec='black'
    )
    axout.add_patch(rect)
    
    conn = ConnectionPatch(
        xyA=arrow_start, coordsA=rect.get_transform(),
        xyB=arrow_end, coordsB=axin.transAxes,
        arrowstyle='->'
    )
    fig.add_artist(conn)
    return rect, conn


fig, axes = plt.subplots(
    2, 2, figsize=(6, 6), 
    gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.05, 'hspace': 0.05, 'left':.1, 'right': .9}
)
Z2 = np.random.rand(512, 512)

imshow_kws = dict(interpolation='gaussian', cmap='RdBu', origin='lower')
raw_ax = axes[0, 0]
raw_ax.imshow(Z2, **imshow_kws)

# inset axes...
axes[1, 0].imshow(Z2, **imshow_kws)
axes[1, 0].set(xlim=(100, 150), ylim=(85, 135))
indicate_inset(axes[1, 0], raw_ax, arrow_start=(.5, 0), arrow_end=(.5, 1))

# # inset axes...
axes[1, 1].imshow(Z2, **imshow_kws)
axes[1, 1].set(xlim=(400, 450), ylim=(200, 250))
indicate_inset(axes[1, 1], raw_ax, arrow_start=(.5, 0), arrow_end=(0, 1))

# # # inset axes...
axes[0, 1].imshow(Z2, **imshow_kws)
axes[0, 1].set(xlim=(400, 450), ylim=(400, 450))
indicate_inset(axes[0, 1], raw_ax, arrow_start=(1, 0), arrow_end=(0, .5))

fig.savefig('test.png') # This is the image uploaded to this answer
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like what I was after and I think I'll be able to modify it to exactly what I need. However, I am getting a type error when using indicate_inset `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. I printed through the function and everything seems to be working; even asking for the return objects from indicate_inset seems to be working i.e `a, b = indicate_inset(axes[1, 0], raw_ax, arrow_start=(.5, 0), arrow_end=(.5, 1))` returns rect and conn. However, it doesn't plot what you have above and just returns the type error.

Comment: Do you know why the type error is occuring?

Comment: My initial guess is the version difference in `matplotlib`. Let me test it out and I'll add another comment

Comment: poking through the [old documentation for `ConnectionPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch) it seems that it only accepts strings for `coordsA` and `coordsB` arguments instead of arbitrary transforms. This feature was implemented in `matplotlib 3.1.0`. Are you able to upgrade?

Comment: No I can't unfortunately; using pip and trying to upgrade, I continually get the error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.1.0`.

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way. If no one has provided anything that works by tomorrow, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: To make this backwards compatible, you could use `coordsA='data'` and then use the actual data coordinates of edge of the box (i.e. derive where you want to be from `x0`, `x1`, `y0` and `y1`). And then `coordsB='axes_fraction'` should work with the same `arrow_end` you currently use.

Comment: @tmdavison thanks heaps for the suggestion, I'll give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: @tmdavison I made the changes you stated i.e changed coordsA and coordsB to `'data'` and `'axes_fraction'` but it gives an attribute error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transData'`. I'm a bit confused on what is happening. Would you be able to post the modified code?